# How to get the Crash Log from Apple?

Tags: ios, emulation, appstore-approval

We developed an app, and it works perfectly on several different emulators and devices, not once crashed, but both times we tried submitting to Apple it gets back to us as "2.1 - apps that crash are rejected" (or something).

I cant seem to find the log from them, or any additional infos. Is the crash log available anywhere? Or just ANY info? They only say that it crashed on an iPad 3rd Gen with iOS 6. We ran on a device like that and it didnt crash for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't provide detailed logs of their review process, although crash logs are sometimes provided, as indicated by @jsd in the comments below.

In theory, crash reports get synchronized with iTunes and can be collected by Apple and provided to you via iTunes Connect, but in practice, that rarely works - or only with large delays.

However, you could integrate some Crash Reporting into your App. Here are a few services that allow you to do that without much hassle:

- [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net)
- [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com)
- [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com)
- [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com)

Crash reporting integration in production versions of my apps have been proven to be very helpful, so I'd highly recommend this. Good crash reporting services provide an SDK to be included in your app, and generate symbolicated, readable, ready-to-use crash reports that make tracking bugs very easy.

As for the cause of your app's crash, here are some basic guesses:

1. Do you use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)? You should.
2. Did you run the Static Analyzer in Xcode (`Product ➞ Analyze`)?
3. Did you test with different environments (e.g. internet connection via 3G, WiFi or none at all)?
4. Have you deleted and reinstalled the app on your device, or did you just update it?

Comment: Apple does send crash reports generated from App Review.  They did for me, anyway.

Comment: @jsd: Interesting. Did they send them to you via e-mail or provide them in iTunes Connect? Did you use Xcode's **Organizer** to symbolicate?

Comment: The crash logs were attached to the rejection email.  I dragged them into Xcode and they were symbolicated. In the particular case that I remember it was due to a timeout on startup because I wasn't checking for network availability, and they always test your apps in airplane mode first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I didnt receive the crash log by email :/. Do you know if those Crash Reporting Apps work even when the crash is on startup? I will check with the iOS developer on these 4 guesses you tried, thanks.

Comment: @rottz Those crash reporting libs work remarkably well in all situations. However, they don't send the crash report immediately; instead, the user is prompted when he launches the app again if he wants to submit it. If the app crashes *very* early, it's possible that the user never gets to this dialog. However, those situations have been rare in my experience.

Comment: Just an addition, the latest HockeyApp SDK for iOS has a way to detect those scenarios, but have modify your startup code to handle that as well.  The documentation contains an example on how to do that.

Comment: I use TestFlight for crash reporting, it is automatic. The user isn't prompted.  check them out: testflightapp.com.  Lots of good stuff there.

Comment: For privacy reasons the user should always be prompted! The HockeyApp SDK gives you the option to send automatically or let the user decide to send once or always.

Comment: Necroing this with an experience of my own, I got the following response when I asked for crash logs and which iPad model they used to encounter the crash:

"We are unable to provide information regarding our review environment.

All apps submitted to the App Store must function correctly and provide access to all features and content at the time of review, regardless of network, device capability, location, etc.

Please refer to our previous messages for information about the issues we encountered during our initial review."

- A joke.